# Block Advertisements from using autofocus to steal the cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ads

Some ads on my site have an input field with the autofocus attribute. When these ads load they take the cursor and, in some cases, cause the page to scroll down to the ad. This behavior is highly aggressive and annoying for users.

When these ads are reported we can block them in our ad network. But they still seem to crop up. I'm wondering if there is a way to block the advertisements from being able to use autofocus to begin with using JavaScript? I still want to allow users to click into the field and interact with the ad if desired so I don't want to block the ability for it to have the focus entirely.

I can't imagine that I'm the only one who has run into this problem, so I'm curious if anyone has found a good solution.

Comment: Maybe choose a better ad provider?

Comment: I'm not the person who setup the ad network, but I'm pretty sure these ads are coming through reputable providers such as Google.